# React-Native DrawerLayoutAndroid Show Menu on Icon Click

Tags: android, react-native

Wanted to understand whether someone was able to use the DrawerLayoutAndroid in react-native along with a Home Icon. The [React API documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html#) content provide me with only callback functions. The layout works fine and displays the requied menu as well as the navigation menu when dragged, but in addition to that wanted to be able to open the menu on click of an icon placed on the Toolbar/top of the screen. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method, available which supports this, `openDrawer`. This can be referenced using the ref callback available in react through which you can get an instance of what was rendered (in this case `DrawerLayoutAndroid`, on which one can call the openDrawer method.

Got the following references from react support
- [Link containing code on how i got this to work for further reference](http://stick2code.blogspot.in/2015/11/react-native-drawerlayoutandroid-how-to.html)

- [method in react](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/2c7de35dee347b5d9a40b4e87862622e60ddf7d9/Libraries/Components/DrawerAndroid/DrawerLayoutAndroid.android.js#L183)
- [Issue reference to update the document](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3897)
- [Issue raised on git by me](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3955)